# SQL query that counts the number of projects for each couple of Benefit/complexity

Tags: sql, count

There is a table called `TBL`. in the database with 3 columns namely

- Project
- Benefit
- Complexity

and the sample data will be like below

```
Project Benefit   Complexity
Prj1    High        Easy
Prj2    High        Medium 
Prj3    Medium      Easy      
Prj4    Low         Easy         
Prj5    High        Medium 
Prj6    Low         Easy
```

I want a query to output the result as below

```
Benefit Complexity Projectcount 
High    Easy         1 
High    Medium       2  
Medium  Easy         1
Low     Easy         2
```

I want an SQL query in order to count the number of project for each couple of Benefit/complexity and to get the output as above .

Comment: what SQL flavour do you use?

Comment: Questions ask here should be beneficial to future visitors. IMO this wouldn't be.

Answer (score 3):

use `COUNT()` aggregate function and grouped them by `Benefit` and `Complexity`.

```
SELECT  Benefit, Complexity, COUNT(*) ProjectCount
FROM    TBL
GROUP   BY Benefit, Complexity
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c0c2/1)

OTHER Source(s)

- [SQL **GROUP BY** clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Benefit, Complexity, COUNT(1) AS NumberOfProjects
FROM TBL
GROUP BY  Benefit, Complexity
```

Or do

```
GROUP BY Complexity, Benefit
```

Note that GROUP BY will do the aggregation based on the order of the columns you give it. So in the first sample it would group projects by benefit and for each benefit group split it by Complexity. In the second example it groups it by Complexity and then the groups are split by benefit. For count you get the same result.